# Deleted answer for UPnP Port Forwarding on ESP8266

Tags: support, deleted-answers, specific-answer

I have extensively thickened my answer after it was deleted, added a lot of explaining as to how the package and UPnP port forwarding works with IGD API:
[ESP8266 UPnP Port Forwarding - IoT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44461516/esp8266-upnp-port-forwarding-iot/46267791#46267791)

Can someone please have a look at it and help me restore it?
I have flagged it to have a moderator look at it, but got no response yet.

Comment: That question is actually off-topic for Stack Overflow, sorry.

Comment: At the same time, I've undeleted your answer but there is no guarantee the *question* will remain on Stack Overflow. As for posting about personal OSS projects, I recommend you read [How to offer personal open-source libraries?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/229085)

Comment: @Martijn, not sure the close reason is correct for that, as I understand it's asking how to programmatically use UPNP to open a port from the ESP8266 which is a programmable device. Although it's possibly too broad / a library request.

Comment: @PeterJ: that's not clear at all. It reads as if that chip is embedded on a router and they want to know if they can configure it for UPNP. It certainly is too broad too, yes.

Comment: @Martijn, they're a small programmable microcontroller with WiFi, so can be programmed in C etc. They're not an end-user type product.

Comment: @MartijnPieters If my biased opinion matters, "Is it possible to use the UPNP protocol for automatic port forwarding on the router using ESP8266" while the sentence can be ambiguous to some, ESP8266 is known to be WiFi capable C programmable device, and many developers choose to use static router port forwarding rules, I really struggled with it and this is why I made the package. I think someone that  struggled with it will understand the sentence correctly. And while UPnP is a protocol, the question is based on a very specific problem which is automatic port forwarding for ESP8266.

Comment: It is a software question, but it is just next to impossible for anybody to see.  As-is the question is entirely too broad and the OP isn't going to repair it, he hasn't been back for the past 3 months.  Consider editing the question, not so sure how you could pull that off.  Good luck.

Comment: I stand corrected! I've re-closed as Too Broad.